# jQuery and CSS - modifying text and restyling it

Tags: jquery, css

My jQuery code brings new text, and new styles. When I update the styles, and then bring new text, the new styles go away. I expected the new styles to stick. Does that make sence? below is an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/titani/SRVa7/6/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.column').addClass('color2') ;

    $('#text').html("<div class='column'>Text22</div>");

    //$('.column').addClass('color2') ;


});
```

Comment: So you add a class to an element that doesn't exist, and you want to know why it doesn't work? That's like walking into an empty room, saying "Hi Bob!", and when Bob walks into the room you wondering why Bob doesn't know you said hi.

Comment: I thought the element exists. The element is defined in HTML, before JS executes. I only modified the element with JS. Here is the html code: <div id="text">
    
    <div id="row" class='color1'>
        Text
    </div>
    
    
</div>

Comment: Not according to the code you posted. Where does `$('.column')` exist already?

Comment: I updated the example. I modify the class first. Then I make div that uses this class. The modified class is not used. http://jsfiddle.net/SRVa7/10/

Comment: `$('.my-class').css('color', 'red');` applies inline CSS to all elements that have the class `.my-class`. It doesn't re-write the CSS class you defined.

Comment: I thought it re-writes the class. Now it makes sense to me. Is there anything that rewrites the class?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your order is wrong, you're adding a class then replacing the element with one without the class, you should do:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    $('#text').html("<div class='column'>Text22</div>");
    $('.column').addClass('color2') ;    

});
```

Alternatively, you could do:

`$('#text').html("<div class='column color2'>Text22</div>");`

To ensure the element has the required class the moment its added.

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the order of your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#text').html("<div class='column'>Text22</div>");
    $('.column').addClass('color2');
});
```

Your code is not working because you add class `color2` to `.column` div but `.column` is not yet exist in the DOM. So you need to add it to the DOM first which is in your case, present after setting `.column` as inner HTML of `#test` div.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SRVa7/8/)**

Comment: I updated the example. I modify the class first. Then I make div that uses this class. The modified class is not used. jsfiddle.net/SRVa7/10

Comment: The default text color is black. You can use different color such as red. Here is the updated fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/SRVa7/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/SRVa7/11/)